# MySQL database not loading after redirecting to a new page

Tags: php, mysql, random, header

Having problem with the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("abc", $con);

$ids = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($ids==0){
    $id = rand (0,50);
    header("Location: http://index.php?id=$id");
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abcdatabase WHERE id = '$id'");

if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "{$row['username']}<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

After redirecting to a new page, such as `http://index.php/?id=38`, MySQL database is not loading I think. Because the line `echo "{$row['username']}<br>";` not displaying anything and also not showing any error message. Actually I'm not understanding what is the wrong I'm making. I'm a novice programmer. Anyone please help me to come up with the issue.

Comment: is there a row in `abcdatabase` table with `id = 38`?

Comment: @Wilq Yes, there is a row in abcdatabase with id=38

Answer (score 1):

For starters you shouldn't use the mysql library anymore because it's deprecated. Use mysqli library instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Secondly you have a little bug. In line 8 you set the $ids variable but in line 19 you don't use it. You use $id there, which would be empty. So you search for id = empty and your query succeeds (you have a result: no records found) so no error message, but you also don't get a name (because no records found). So replace

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abcdatabase WHERE id = '$id'");
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM abcdatabase WHERE id = '$ids'");
```

In general, if your code expects to find 1 result, also add a check that you really find one and add an error message if you don't. Replace

```
if (!$result) {
  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}
```

with

```
if (!$result) {
  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
  exit;
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($result) <> 1) {
  echo 'No records found';
  exit;
}
```

Thirdly, there's the header bug like Joachim explained.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very very much. I really appreciate your answer. Excellent bug search. I don't have enough reputation score to vote up the answer. But thank you very very much for finding the bug. It works well now.

Comment: You're welcome. You could vote me up once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
$id = rand(0, 50);
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
```

You should also at least escape the id-variable before inserting it into a SQL query, using

```
$escapedId = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is imho not needed here as there is already the even more restrictive intval.